# Unity google street view pano image

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Google Street View to create VR genre content.
We now have to load Google Street View 360 panoramic images, which is where we have difficulty.
What I want to do is to load the panorama image and apply it to the material. Most of the applications I've seen are the combination of each heaing value and pitch value.
And the resolution was limited to 640 pixels.
I want to know how to import high-resolution panoramic images, but I have not been able to get the material I wanted to search from many places.
I am asking if there is anyone who knows how.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=" + mapWidth + "x" + mapHeight + "&location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&fov=" + fov + "&heading=" + heading + "&pitch=" + pitch + "&key" + key;
WWW www = new WWW(url);
yield return www;
img.texture = www.texture;
img.SetNativeSize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a cubemap from these. Just take 6 images in 90 degrees rotation increments (one for each face) and place in the correct order.

See how the image below can be mapped to a cube?

[image: face-6]
[image: face-1]
[image: face-2]
[image: face-3]
[image: face-4]
[image: face-5]

As for the resolution, here's a quote from Google Documentation: [Get API Key and Signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/usage-and-billing)

> Image Sizes
>   Street View images can be returned in any size up to 640 x 640 pixels.
>   Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers who are correctly signing their URLs can request images up to 2048 x 2048 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But can not I get the original panoramic image of that image?

Comment: Probably not without paying for maps premium or (possibly unethical) url hacking of the Google maps web app. There is a chance that the app doesn't serve high quality panoramas this way anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It has helped a lot. There were some visible problems in the image, but I solved some problems.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.